# Router communicating with webserver on lan

Tags: linux, networking, router, raspberry-pi

I opened an http port (80) on my raspberry pi and I am running iptraf to monitor my network.
I noticed that my router is "connecting" to my pi to the http port(?)
Can anyone explain what is going on?has my network/router ben compromised?
I am fairly new to Linux and I would like to know why is my router communicating to my pi(websrv) on an http port ,because as far as I know, it shouldn't do that(or?)
here is a log from iptraf & hardware/software information.

> [pastebin log](http://pastebin.com/urhA7R5T)
>
> seyenet = router @ tp-link tl-wr1043ND runing gargoyle firmware
> pegasus = websrv @ raspberry pi archlinux arm

Comment: Is your router forwarding port 80 to your raspberry pi?

Comment: yes the port is open to the world wide web & pointed to the rbi

Comment: Then people/scripts are connecting to it. It shows up as "coming from seyenet" because on your local network, the incoming traffic is coming from the router. (Everything on the internet is continuously scanned by scripts from all over, mostly looking for things to exploit and turn into spam relays, so it doesn't matter that you haven't linked it anywhere, or it has no proper name, or whatever. It's online, and things are finding it already).

Comment: yes but, if i connect to it via my other machine, it shows up that vesuiv is trying to connect with wwwserv, or from anyother machine it shows the machine name, or if its accessed from outside the lan, it shows by who, it doesnt show the router..

Comment: OK; what webserver is the Pi running? (Apache?) Look in the logs for it and it should tell you what web address the router is trying to get to. Or use iptraf (or tcpdump) to capture the whole network traffic - HTTP is not encrypted - and that will show you what the router is trying to load.

Comment: apache, the router is trying to get loads of stuff from what i can see from the logs, im only using iptraf on my raspberry pi(wwwsrv)

Comment: somehow it managed to send itself(the msg above) i have no idea how to configure iptraf to monitore the whole network. yeah i think u got it right with ur 1st msg usr conn thru router thats why router came up before in iptraf, but still makes no sens how it came up when no1 connected :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure something on your Pi is making DNS requests. UDP port 53 is known as "domain" and your pastebin shows what appears to be a perfectly normal DNS request from pegasus to seyenet followed by a response from the router:

*Mon Mar 10 23:53:15 2014; UDP; eth0; 60 bytes; source MAC address b8:27:eb:bc:8f:c9; from pegasus.own.net:40923 to seyenet.own.net:domain*

A 60 byte UDP packet was sent from a random high source port on the Pi to port 53 on the router. That's generally what you'll see in a DNS lookup request.

*Mon Mar 10 23:53:15 2014; UDP; eth0; 76 bytes; source MAC address a0:f3:c1:16:5d:b0; from seyenet.own.net:domain to pegasus.own.net:40923*

A 76 byte packet sent from the router's DNS port back to the issuing port on the Pi. Most likely, the DNS response.

Without seeing a packet capture I can't be certain but that would be my analysis.

Comment: This looks like normal DNS traffic to me. There's absolutely nothing unusual or suspicious about it.

Comment: amazing man! thanks & ty for ur time, much appreciated